# iPhone X Keyboard Notification Height Differs

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I've had this strange occurrence recently when I've been using `keyboardWillShow` and `keyboardWillShow` where the initial call of getting the height of the keyboard from `(notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue` returns a value of 477px and then all other time afterwards it says the value is now 535px, which is 58px larger. However, visually, the keyboard hasn't changed in appearance whatsoever. The predictive bar is enabled for both keyboards.

As background info, the purpose of needing the keyboard height is to offset the scroll of a tableview in which each cell contains a textfield and I'm comparing the position of the textfield to see if it's hidden behind the keyboard when editing begins.

Am I missing something in how my methodology of understanding this works?

Comment: Update: Calling `UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` seems to be consistent in calling 477px.

Comment: Yes, it works fine with `keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`.  Thanks.

Comment: I also getting same issue in ios 13
I am getting frame like this : 

            let keyboardFrame = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! CGRect

and i am getting diffrent value for frame

Logs 

keyboardFrame : ---- (0.0, 550.0, 414.0, 346.0)
keyboardFrame : ---- (0.0, 506.0, 414.0, 390.0)

Comment: Do you have any solution?

Comment: @Anita I have posted the answer, maybe a bit late :D

Comment: Thank you @Latenec , but yes it actually too late :) , still thanks for posting answer :)

Answer (score 1):

May this help you it is working for me fine

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(CommentsVC.keyboardWillShow), name: 
 NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
                    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(CommentsVC.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

@objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: NSNotification) {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                    self.inputContainerViewBottom.constant = 0


                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()


                }
            }


@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: NSNotification) {
                print(notification)
                let keyboardFrame = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as AnyObject).cgRectValue
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                    self.inputContainerViewBottom.constant = keyboardFrame!.height

                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()


                    let flag = self.tableComments.isCellVisible(section: 0, row: 10 - 1)

                    if flag
                    {
                        self.scrollToBottom()
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }

                }
            }
```

**Note: inputContainerViewBottom is the outlet of bottom constraint**

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the similar scenario and the solution was basically this:

```
func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
        let animationDuration = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double,
        let keyboardEndFrame = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
    else { return }

    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
    let bottomPadding = window?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0.0 // This is the key
    buttonConstraint.constant = keyboardEndFrame.height - bottomPadding
    UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration) { [weak self] in
        self?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

iPhone X (and other devices with OLED) has `safeAreaInsets`, which is added in your case.

Comment: thanks, this solved it for me: `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0.0`